# Flask JWT with RESTful api

Tags: flask, jwt, flask-jwt

How to use JWT with RESTful?

It works

```
@app.route('/test_route')
@jwt_required()
def protected():
    return '%s' % current_identity
```

But what to do in this case?

```
api.add_resource(testApi, '/test_api')
```

I cannot find this case in the Flask-JWT documentation

Answer (score 0):

You can try out something like this:

```
class TestApi(Resource):
     @jwt_required()
     def get(self):
         return '%s' % current_identity
```

later use this:
api.add_resource(TestApi, '/test_api')